# what would be a better environment for a linux based retail Point of Sales program?

Tags: 14.04

I'm looking at standard Ubuntu, Lubuntu, or Xubuntu. I was just wondering which would be a better environment for a retail store?

I will be using Lemon POS to start with but I am considering building my own once i learn how to do that.

Comment: I think more information would be useful to answer your question. Are you looking to install a pre-existing POS package such as Lemon POS? Or are you developing your own package?

Comment: I'm probably gonna start with Lemon POS but developing my own package would be better, i just don't know how to do anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Lemon POS depends heavily on KDE dependencies, as such Kubuntu (Uses the KDE Desktop environment.) would definitely be the place to start looking. Also take the specifications into account as Lemon POS can work on any desktop environment as the needed dependencies will be installed automatically, however if KDE is to heavy for the system Xubuntu or Lubuntu may be a better choice.